# How do I allocate memory for a pointer to an array of char *?

Tags: c, memory, multidimensional-array, allocation

Could someone please explain how to correctly allocate memory for for a pointer to an array of pointer of characters in c? For example:

```
char *(*t)[];
```

I try to do it like this:

```
*t = malloc( 5 * sizeof(char*));
```

This gives me a compile error:

```
error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
```

Any assistance on this would be great! Thanks

Comment: Think of the array as a pointer as well - so you end up allocating memory for pointer to a pointer. ie allocate space for the array of pointers then allocate each 'string' in turn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
char **t = (char**)malloc( <no of elements> * sizeof(char*));
```

That allocates the array of pointers.

```
for (i = 0 ; i< <no of elements> ; i++)
{
    t[i] = (char*)malloc( <length of text> * sizeof(char));
}
```

That allocates memory for the text that each element of the array points to.

Comment: I think this is more along the lines of what I am trying to do, however coding it gives me an error. wouldn't it be: (*t)[i] = malloc( <length of text> * sizeof(char); Which, please correct me If I am wrong but is saying allocate space for an array of pointers at the address t points to.

Comment: I think you should add the definition of `t` to complete your example.

Comment: @DustyCampbell Have edited my answer. It wasn't complete and i had left out the type-casting and the definition of t. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When people say "a pointer to an array of X", usually they really mean a pointer to *the first element* of an array of X. Pointer-to-array types are very clunky to use in C, and usually only come up in multi-dimensional array usage.

With that said, the type you want is simply `char **`:

```
char **t = malloc(num_elems * sizeof *t);
```

Using a pointer-to-array type, it would look like:

```
char *(*t)[num_elems] = malloc(sizeof *t);
```

Note that this will be a C99 variable-length array type unless `num_elems` is an *integer constant expression* in the formal sense of the term.

Comment: The second statement "char (*t)[num_elems] = malloc(sizeof *t)" doesn't seem to make sense to me, could u explain it further.  When you dereference the memory for the allocation, it wouldn't return the memory space allocated with num_elements. What effect does is have by using that extra syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "when you dereference the memory for the allocation"? There's no dereferencing in any of the code I gave.

Comment: I still don't understand why you would allocated memory in this way :-(,  Why would u say
char *(*t)[num_elems] dereferencing aside.

Comment: sizeof is an operator and doesn't it need a parenthesis after it? `sizeof ( type-name )`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends how you want it to be allocated, but here is one way.

```
char** myPointer = malloc(sizeof(char *) * number_Of_char_pointers)
int i;
for(i = 0; i <  number_Of_char_pointers; i++)
{
     myPointer[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * number_of_chars);
}
```

something to note is that myPointer[i] is almost exactly identical to saying *(myPointer + i), when being used to dereference a variable, not during initialization.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    char** a = new char* [100];
    delete []a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for `void main`, and another -1 for a C++ answer to a C question, if I could...